# How to fix "cannot import name '***'" in python

Tags: python

I'm using python3.6 and I'm having this error:

> "ImportError: cannot import name 'video_transforms'".

I'm trying to import using:

```
from . import video_transforms as transforms
```

This video_transform.py file is this file:

https://github.com/cypw/PyTorch-MFNet/blob/master/data/video_transforms.py

And he is importing this file:

https://github.com/cypw/PyTorch-MFNet/blob/master/data/image_transforms.py

Once I had this problem inside my program, I decided to do something simpler, I went into python shell and just did:

```
from . import video_transforms as transforms
```

Got the same error.

I read a lot about this error, and I found most of the people got this because of circular problems, but here I can't see that this si the case.

I'll be happy for your help,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Replace this**:

```
from . import video_transforms as transforms
```

**With this**:

```
from .import video_transforms as transforms
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I can't find anything in the docs about that space being significant...

Answer (score 0):

You can try `sys.path.append('path/to/file')` before the import

Comment: Strange because for me this works.
`sys.path.append("C:/Users/tibszucs/Desktop/")
import video_transforms`

Answer (score 0):

The `.` indicates, that you want to load from a package the module is in ([see here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html))

Effectively you'll have to import the functions into the package namespace. You want the following file layout:

```
app.py
data/
  __init__.py
  video_transforms.py
  image_transforms.py
```

In your `/data/__init__.py` you can then do an relative import

```
from . import video_transforms
```

However, this assumes that your program lives in app.py
There you can do something like

```
from data import video_transforms
```

Comment: I have main.py and those two files in the save directory.
so I created an __init__.py file with the line you said.
and than I tried to import using:
"import .video_transforms as video_transforms"
this gave me a syntax error.
And When I import using:
"from .import video_transforms as transforms"
Still getting the same error...
Did I understand your solution correctly?

Comment: @albert1905 It must be an __init__.py file, I edited the answer to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

I got this headache many times. The dot `.` in `import` (or `from`) lines says that this file is trying to import something from other files when we treat all the files wrapped inside a so-called `package`.

I just clone `Pytorch-MFNet` from Github to reproduce your error. The code itself is nothing wrong and runnable.

Two ways for you to test the code in `ipython` or `Python Shell` (I recommend using `ipython` since we can use `Tab` for text completion):

#### Treat all the files in data as the modules of package `data`.

So, you open your python shell outside `data` directory.

```py
# cd ./Pytorch-MFNet  ---> Now we are in Pytorch-MFNet directory

# import anything you want in data package.
# any lines below work properly, take one to test

from data import video_transforms
from data.video_transforms import *
import data.video_transforms as video_transforms

# test
to_tensor = video_transforms.ToTensor()
```

#### Treat all the files in `data` as normal modules

So, you can go inside the `data` directory and import anything from files.
However, you must remove `.` in `video_transforms.py` as follows:

```py
# in video_transforms.py

from image_transforms import Compose, \
                              Transform, \
                              Normalize, \
                              Resize, \
                              RandomScale, \
                              CenterCrop, \
                              RandomCrop, \
                              RandomHorizontalFlip, \
                              RandomRGB, \
                              RandomHLS
```

Now go to `data` directory and enjoy your checking with the following code in python shell

```py
# cd ./Pytorch-MFNet/data

from video_transforms import *
from video_transforms import ToTensor

# any above code should work!
```

Hope this helps.